# Highlighting the area of sub-figure that has been zoomed in the second sub-figure

Tags: subcaption, zooming

I am using `\subcaption` package to display two images, where the second image is the zoom in version of the first image. I use the below code to display the images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{a.png}
        \caption{All components} \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure}
    \par \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{b.png}
        \caption{Zoom in view of a single component} \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Test} \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I get the following figure as an output.

[image]

However, I want to highlight the part in 1st image that has been zoomed in the second image. Something like this. Also can the captions of image (a) be displayed above the line.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit using captions above lines**

Steps:

1. Find the points needed to be connected
2. node at these points
3. The connection (lines or whatever) with overlay tikzpicture.
4. Find the points for the captions and comment out real captions.
5. Add `\captionof` in minipages on specific points.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelsep=space,labelformat = parens}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}

Text before


\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{example-image-a}};
%\fill[red] (-2.6,-1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step find points using circles 
%\fill[red] (-1.8,-1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step
\node(A) at (-2.6,-1.85){}; % Second step: nodes on the points found by first step
\node(B) at (-1.8,-1.85){}; % Second step
\node(E) at (0,-2.6){}; %Fourth step find positions for captions
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{All components} \label{fig:a} %Commented on fourth step
\end{subfigure}
\par \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{example-image-b}};
%\fill[red] (-4.8,1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step find points using circles 
%\fill[red] (4.8,1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step
\node(C) at (-4.8,1.85) {}; % Second step: nodes on the points found by first step
\node(D) at (4.8,1.85) {}; % Second step
\node(F) at (0,-2.6){}; %Fourth step
\end{tikzpicture}
%\caption{Zoom in view of a single component} \label{fig:b} %Commented on fourth step
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Test} \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] %Third step: connect points
   \draw[-,blue,thick] (A.center)--(C.center); %Third step
   \draw[-,blue, thick] (B.center)--(D.center); %Third step
   \node at (E) {\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} %Fifth Step
\captionof{subfigure}{All components}\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}
};
   \node at (F) {\begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth} %Fifth step
\captionof{subfigure}{Zoom in view of a single component}\label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

Text continues here

\end{document}
```

Result like below but with the caption above the lines

**Old Answer**
Here is a tikz solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
Text before
\begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (0,0){\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{example-image-a}};
%\fill[red] (-2.6,-1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step find points using circles 
%\fill[red] (-1.8,-1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step
\node(A) at (-2.6,-1.85){}; % Second step: nodes on the points found by first step
\node(B) at (-1.8,-1.85){}; % Second step
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All components} \label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\par \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip \bigskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.8\textwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3.7cm]{example-image-b}};
%\fill[red] (-4.8,1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step find points using circles 
%\fill[red] (4.8,1.85) circle (3pt); % <-First step
\node(C) at (-4.8,1.85) {}; % Second step: nodes on the points found by first step
\node(D) at (4.8,1.85) {}; % Second step
\end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Zoom in view of a single component} \label{fig:b}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Test} \label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay] %Third step: connect points
   \draw[-,blue,thick] (A.center)--(C.center); %Third step
   \draw[-,blue, thick] (B.center)--(D.center); %Third step
\end{tikzpicture}
Text continues here
\end{document}
```

I have commented the code in 3 steps:

1. Find the points needed to be connected
2. node at these points
3. The connection (lines or whatever) with overlay tikzpicture.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there any specific way to find the exact coordinates. Or the only way is hit and trial

Comment: you mentioned that one of the code sample that you provided shows captions above the line. But I tried both the codes and found that the caption of figure (a), in both the code sample remains below the line.

Comment: The `y` coordinate for the corners is the half of the height you gave to your images. the `x` needs some tests (can be calculated if you know exact dimensions)

Comment: Try `\captionof{subfigure}{\color{red} \bfseries All components}\label{fig:a}` in the edited code. It is clear that it is above with this way

Comment: You can try: \captionof{subfigure}{\colorbox{white}{All components}}\label{fig:a} if you prefer. Are you there? Do you want to move to chat?

Comment: ah I see, the caption was already above the line. however, the 2nd option that you gave using `\colorbox{white}`, does the magic which I required. Thank you so much once again, it was a great help!

Comment: Welcome! For `x` coord of (A) you can try: `\dimexpr-0.5\linewidth+\dimexpr 4\linewidth/23\relax\relax` and of (B): `\dimexpr-0.5\linewidth+\dimexpr 7\linewidth/23\relax\relax` the others [(C) and (D)] are `0.5\linewidth` and `-0.5\linewidth`.